# Cortana channel cannot be added

Tags: botframework, cortana

I am having an issue after migrating my Bot to Azure. I have a Bot that is up and running on Cortana Chanel as well. I previously published it only for me ‘Deployed to self’ so I can see it on my Cortana Canvas but now I want to publish it for group of people but I am unable to do it from Azure portal. Whenever I click on ‘Edit’ button of Cortana Channel through Azure Portal following error prompts me:

[image]

As per the error they are expecting me to use my Microsoft Personal Account (i.e. Hotmail or Outlook Account) but unfortunately in my case it’s not possible. I have azure subscriptions in my office account not in my personal account that’s why I migrated all my bots to my office account and now trying to configure it for other peoples (i.e. Deployment for Group) but because of the above error I could not do it. As I know previously it was very straight forward all we have to go to ‘Cortana Dashboard’ and there is an option of deployment by which we can easily publish our skill sets to the group of people by just adding there email address.

Could you please help me how can I resolve this issue? All I want to use my azure account (i.e. my company account) to configure the Cortana channel and other things like Deployment to Group of peoples.

Comment: As of right now there is no resolution to your problem.  You simply must use an MSA account

Comment: Is there any way to get my office account subscriptions to my MSA account?

Comment: not that I am aware of, but you could try to add that email address to you MSA account.  I assume this would not work though.

Comment: This is still an issue. What's the intended workaround for this? My current plan is to create two instances of the bot so that I can get Skype for Business and Cortana, but that is pretty gnarly.